# How to efficiently quickscope using Shaft

Tags: tanki-online

In my hours spent playing Sandbox CTF, I have only ever seen 2 shafts (which didn't switch equipment within 2 minutes of joining).

They would drive parallel to the wall, scoping just before passing the edge, then,  drifting with momentum, fire a moderately-charged shot at one of my teammates.  With double power, this was enough to knockout anything weaker than a Dictator.

Fascinated by this tactic, I tried doing it myself.  But I kept:

1. Scoping too early and end up looking at the edge of the wall.
2. Scoping too late and getting a bad angle to shoot from.
3. Not adjusting my aim fast enough.

Are there any good techniques to quick-scoping on Sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this technique is easier with mouse controls because your firing fingers are much more coordinated with your turning hand. I tried this with keyboard controls before, but it has some problems because of your hand position. Now, to to it very well, you have to practise this a lot (Like the other skills that you use in Tanki) in order for it to work near-seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would just create an empty map the practice in and just get used to the timings of how far you actually go when you scope. Do this by driving from the edge of the map towqrds the wall. Then as soon as you reach the corner press space and then remember where you got up to. That is around the space you would start scoping.